# 'data-target' property becomes 'target' when compiling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I want to use an anchor for calling a modal from a multiple times used angular-directive for each instance.
This is the anchor:

```
<li>
   <a role="button" 
      data-toggle="modal" 
      data-target="#editModal{{tweet.id}}"
    >Edit</a>
</li>
```

But when I use the `{{ }}`, the compiled html code shows only a

```
target="#editModal24"
```

and therefor the call doesn't work.

When I manually change to the **data-target** property in the browser, everything works.

Any ideas how to prevent that?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular normalizes attribute name

```
private _normalizeAttributeName(attrName: string): string {
  return /^data-/i.test(attrName) ? attrName.substring(5) : attrName;
}
```

*Note:* even `<div data-*ngIf="3">Hello</div>` will work without problem.

And as you use **interpolation** inside attribute then it will be treated as **property binding**

So angular sets `target` property to `a` element.

[HTMLAnchorElement.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)

> Is a DOMString that reflects the target HTML attribute, indicating
>   where to display the linked resource.

That's why you can see the `target` attribute after setting `target` property to anchor element.

If you want to keep `data-target` attribute then use attribute binding like:

Option 1

```
attr.data-target="#editModal{{tweet.id}}"
```

Option 2

```
[attr.data-target]="'#editModal' + tweet.id"
```

Comment: attr.data-target="#editModal{{tweet.id}}" worked for me