# Angular - adding Cypress data-cy attribute

Tags: angular, angular-directive, cypress

I just yesterday started using cypress.io with angular, as the docs say, I'm using the attribute data-cy to specifically target elements

`<div data-cy="myelement">Hello</div>`

`cy.get("[data-cy=myelement]")`

The problem is that angular doesn't recognize the data-cy attribute if I want to bind it dinamically

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user" [data-cy]="user.name">Online</div>
```

Do I have to create a personal directive to add that attribute dinamically? Or there is a better way ?

Comment: I personally use id="something"most of the time, I don't have a issue where my developers are using the ID for any thing. I guess it could cause an issue. Perhaps I should re-think this, but I have never done this... thanks for the post

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices

You want to avoid id because is coupled to styling or JS event listeners.
And you want to use data-cy because Isolated from all changes.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Angular treats `data-` [specially](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19054#issuecomment-327253870) and you may get in trouble when will be creating a directive.

You should be using attribute binding instead:

```
[attr.data-cy]="user.name"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! How haven't I thought of attr...
Is there somewhere in the docs where it states that the data attributes are treated in a different way and how ?

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19054#issuecomment-327253870 and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3d11355fec00be0ff2db25810ae28091398a9d52/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L497 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672595/angular-directive-for-holderjs-expression-evaluation-not-working-as-intended/46673111#46673111 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915264/data-target-property-becomes-target-when-compiling/44917841#44917841

Comment: Its also that `[something]="somethingElse"` is treated as an input binding, so to bind an attribute, you have to use the attribute binding.

Comment: Thank you, this trick just saved me a few hours of head-banging.