# Cypress not picking up html elements

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, cypress

I'm trying to get a handle on a simple html `<p>` tag using the `data-cy` attribute:

```
<p data-cy="register">Register</p>
```

First I mount the component:

```
 it('mounts', () => {
        cy.mount(AccountDialogComponent, {
            imports: [ 
                HttpClientTestingModule, 
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                AngularMaterialModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule
            ],
            declarations: [ AccountDialogComponent ],
            providers: [{provide: AccountService, useValue: accountService}]
        })
    });
```

The test I am running for this as follows:

```
it("text should be 'Register' when user is registering", () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="register"]').should('have.text', 'Register');
});
```

The test keeps returning a failure:

> assertexpected [data-cy="register"] to have text Register, but the
> text was ''

After another few seconds, it then returns an Assertion Error:

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [data-cy="register"], but never found it.

I can't understand why this isn't working?

I am new to Cypress and this is the first test I am dong since installing Cypress in my Angular app.

Comment: where do you have `submitBtn`  in the `html`? somehow that fails before reaching out to `register`

Comment: Apologies, I changed the name of the `data-cy` attribute from `submitBtn` to `register` before I submitted the question. I just forgot to update that part of the question. I've now updated the OP. Both the assertion failure and assertion error relate to the same `<p>` html element

Comment: Just use e2e testing framework in a component testing kind of way. The Cypress component framework is a mess.

Comment: Try changing to `cy.get(...).contains('Register')`

Comment: @Andres2142, tried that but still get the "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [data-cy="register"], but never found it." error

Comment: @E.Maggini, what's up with the component framework?

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, this [Angular - adding Cypress data-cy attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453410/angular-adding-cypress-data-cy-attribute) sorted it out.

The gist is the Angular framework would not pass on `data-cy` without it's particular binding,

```js
<p [attr.data-cy]="register">Register</p>
```

Now,  test code will find your element.

BTW Component testing is ok if `mount()` ok, then it's same syntax for test assertions.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so it seems I was just forgetting that I need to mount the component before each test:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
        cy.mount(AccountDialogComponent, {
            imports: [ 
                HttpClientTestingModule, 
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                AngularMaterialModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule
            ],
            declarations: [ AccountDialogComponent ],
            providers: [{provide: AccountService, useValue: accountService}]
        })
    });
```